# What steps can I take to fix a 'communication with Tableau Protocol Server process was lost' error while embedding a website page on Tableau?

Tags: tableau-desktop

How to find embed website page on tableau?

I'm unable to upload the excel sheet on tableau it is showing as

An error occurred while communicating with Microsoft Excel Reader.

The connection to the data source might have been lost.
The connection to the data source might have been lost.
ExternalProtocol::PipeMessageSource::ReadBytes: Communication with the Tableau Protocol Server process was lost.

So can any one say me the solution for it

Comment: please provide screenshots. Also if you are using excel as data source make sure you take an extract